Highlighting bypass_dnd setting row in Android
I'm trying to highlight the Override Do not Distrub channel setting upon opening the intent.
I have written the code according to this answer:
private const val EXTRA_FRAGMENT_ARG_KEY = ":settings:fragment_args_key"
private const val EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT_ARGUMENTS = ":settings:show_fragment_args"
private const val EXTRA_BYPASS_DND = "bypass_dnd"

// ...

val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS).apply {
    putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, packageName)
    putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, channelId)
    putExtra(EXTRA_FRAGMENT_ARG_KEY, EXTRA_BYPASS_DND)
    putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT_ARGUMENTS,
        bundleOf(EXTRA_FRAGMENT_ARG_KEY to EXTRA_BYPASS_DND))

}
context.startActivity(intent)
Toast.makeText(context,
    "Grant the Override Do not Disturb permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

Unfortunately, the intent opens, but the setting is not highlighted. The bypass_dnd key is taken from the source code.
